# Differentiate a function under Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} g(x;t) dx=g(b(t);t)b'(t)-g(a(t);t)a'(t)+\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(x;t)dx$$
How can I get this sentence? My professor said 'just use chain rule', and I figure it out , but not exactly know how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$F(u,v,t)=\int_u^v g(x,t)\,dx$$
Then
$$\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} g(x,t)\,dx=F(a(t),b(t),t)$$
which you can differentiate using the chain rule. It is easy enough to compute the partial derivatives with respect to $u$ and $v$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: oh Thanks! Chain rule was everything.